# AngularJS - Can't Display Content from JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url-routing

I'm just starting with AngularJS and am having an issue using {{ expressions }} to pull data from JSON that I am getting with $http.get. The JSON object is coming through fine, as I was able to log it to the console. But when I try to display it in my view.html the expressions are empty. Maybe it's just something small, but I can't figure it out.

Code snippets below

Routing Snippet:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/contacts/:contactId', {
     controller: 'ContactController',
     templateUrl: 'js/views/contact.html'
})
.otherwise({
     redirectTo: '/'
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('ContactController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get($routeParams.contactId + '.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.detail = data;
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        return data;
        console.log("Failed to get data")
    });
    $scope.pageClass = 'contact-screen';

}]);
```

Piece of the contact.html view:

```
<div class="text-container">
        <h2 class="name"> {{ detail.name }} </h2>
        <h3 class="subtitle"> "{{ detail.subtitle }}" </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: what does `data` look like?

Comment: @charlietfl

Data is a JSON object that looks like

`[
  {
    "name": "Guiron",

    "subtitle": "Space critter",

    "url": "http://eightninecollective.com/contacts-api/guiron.png",

    "phone": "1-800-SPACE",

    "email": "guiron@spaceplanet.info"

  }
 ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array containing an object for your data , not a single object as your code would currently indicate.

To show just one item as you currently have in view:

```
$scope.detail = data[0];
```

But since you will likely have more than one leave the controller the same and use `ng-repeat` to iterate over the array

```
<div class="text-container" ng-repeat="item in detail">
        <h2 class="name"> {{ item.name }} </h2>
        <h3 class="subtitle"> "{{ item.subtitle }}" </h3>
</div>
```

Alternatively since you have `:contactId` in url, change back end to return a single object and leave your code all the same

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I was ng-repeat in the rest of the site but not this part and now with it added, everything works great.